# How to add thousand separators when using gg_miss_upset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, missing-data, separator

I'm trying to identify missing data patterns graphically using `gg_miss_upset()`. But I haven't been able to include thousand separators.

This is my code

```
figure1 <- gg_miss_upset(NA_data, nset = 6, nintersects = 8).
```

I have tried to add a thousand separator using the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous` argument, but it did not work.

```
figure1 <- gg_miss_upset(NA_data, nset = 6, nintersects = 8) +
   scale_y_continuous(
     labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", scientific = FALSE)
   )
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It seems like `gg_miss_upset()` is not part of a base R library. Could you please add the corresponding `library()` calls to your example code? it is good tone on here and often necessary for understanding your question. 
Also, it would be great if `NA_data` were an actual example dataset containing `NA`s so we could just copy paste your code and run it. A good example may be `airquality`, because it has `NA`s. Making your example easily reproducible by providing necessary libraries and data, you increase your chance for an answer.